# Unexpected loop in my in Prolog program

Tags: prolog

I appropriate your help in this problem:

I am writing a Prolog program and when closing SWI-prolog window while the program is running, it enters in unexpected loop then hung and close!!

I don't know why does this happen?

My code is:

```
start:-
    write('Select one of the options: '),nl,
    write('1- Sum two numbers'),nl,
    write('2- EXIT'),nl,
    getChoice(X),choice(X).

%Validate choice
getChoice(N):- repeat, read(N), validate(N), !.

validate(N):- integer(N), N > 0, N =< 2, ! .
validate(N):- write(N),
    write(' is an invaild menue choice, enter a valid choice: '),
    !, fail.

choice(X):- X is 1, write(' This option for summing two numbers'), start.
choice(X):- X is 2, halt.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: halt/0 quit the process...

Comment: Yes, it does, but I am wondering about the behavior when closing the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have, is a so called **failure driven loop**. Such loops are very error prone, as you are currently experiencing. It suffices to look at:

```
getChoice(N):- repeat, read(N), validate(N), !.
```

So what will happen, if `validate/1` fails? Well, the system will again try to execute `read(N)`. And if you are done, `N` will be unified with `end_of_file`, which again will make `validate(end_of_file)` fail. So, although we are already at the end, we will read past end_of_file. Depending on your system, this might produce another `end_of_file` etc.

In short, these things are extremely hard to follow. Avoid failure driven loops as long as you can. Better, as a beginner, avoid to do I/O manually. Instead, try to stick to the pure part of the language and let the toplevel loop do the printing for you.

In your case, rather write:

```
getChoice(M) :-
   read(N),
   ( N = end_of_file -> fail
   ; validate(N) -> M = N
   ; getChoice(M)
   ).
```

But you cannot learn much from such ugly code. Stick to the pure side.

Comment: Thank you, but do you have another way to check user input and don't proceed unless he gives the right choice?